# Encoding of a column from another column when a specific value is observed r

Tags: r, list, dataframe

An example dataframe and a list that has the information of which column to encode is given below.

```r
# Dataframe

DF <- data.frame("genres" = c("pop", "pop","jazz","rock","jazz","blues","rock","pop","blues","pop"),
           "colors" = c("orange","red","red","orange","green","blue","orange","red","blue","green"),
           "values" = c(12, 15, 24, 33 ,47, 2 , 9 ,6, 89, 75),
           "genres number 12" = c("r","r","?","l","?","r","l","r","r","r"),
           "genres number 17" = c("l","l","?","r","?","l","r","l","l","l"),
           "colors number 3" = c("r","l","l","r","?","r","r","l","r","?"),
           "colors number 10" = c("r","l","l","r","l","r","r","l","r","l"),
           check.names = FALSE
           )

# Encoding list

EncodingList <- list("genres number 17", "colors number 3")
names(EncodingList) <- c("colors number 3", "genres number 12")
```

I want to encode a column from another column when a specific value is observed. For example the first element in the `EncodingList` is `"colors number 3"` and its corresponding name is `"genres number 17"`. When a value is `?` in `"genres number 17"` column of `DF`, we should fill that row with whatever corresponding value `"colors number 3"` has ("r","l" or "?"). The expected output is given below. `EncodingList` is very long, it is preferable to use a loop to iterate through.

```r
  expectedDF <- data.frame("genres" = c("pop", "pop","jazz","rock","jazz","blues","rock","pop","blues","pop"),
           "colors" = c("orange","red","red","orange","green","blue","orange","red","blue","green"),
           "values" = c(12, 15, 24, 33 ,47, 2 , 9 ,6, 89, 75),
           "genres number 12" = c("r","r","?","l","?","r","l","r","r","r"),
           "genres number 17" = c("l","l","l","r","?","l","r","l","l","l"),
           "colors number 3" = c("r","l","l","r","?","r","r","l","r","r"),
           "colors number 10" = c("r","l","l","r","l","r","r","l","r","l"),
           check.names = FALSE
           )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a for loop to update the columns given in *EncodingList* having a `?` with values of another given column.

```
for(i in seq_len(length(EncodingList))) {
    j <- which(DF[,EncodingList[[i]]] == "?")
    DF[j,EncodingList[[i]]] <- DF[j,names(EncodingList)[i]]
}
identical(DF, expectedDF)
#[1] TRUE
```